# How do I print out multiple keys that correspond to the same value in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key, mapping

I am trying to write a code in Python where the user inputs the name of their friend and that friend's favorite color into a dictionary. The program will then take those keys and values and print out the color first (the value) and then every friend (key) who was mapped to that value.

However, I'm having difficulties printing out multiple values on the same line as their shared keys.

Here's my code so far:

```py
color_match = {}
while  True:
    key = input('type in the name: ')
    if key == '0':
        break
    value = input('Enter your friend\'s favorite color: ')
    if not (key and value):
        break
    color_match[key] = value

print(color_match)

print(color_match[key] + ":",key )
```

Let's say my inputs are {'Eric':blue, 'Tom':red, 'Bob':blue}. It yields the following result:

```
blue: Eric
red: Tom
blue: Bob
```

Can anyone help? In this example I would need Bob and Eric to be on the same line corresponding with blue.

Comment: Do you want `color_match["blue"]` to be a list or string?

Comment: I was hoping to keep it a string if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```py
color_match = {}
while True:
    nm = input('Enter the name of your friend: ')
    if nm == '0':
        break
    color  = input('Enter your friend\'s favorite color: ')
    if not (nm and color):
        break
    if color.lower() not in color_match.keys(): color_match[color.lower()]= nm
    else: color_match[color.lower()] += (f", {nm}")

print(color_match)

for key in color_match:
    print(key+ ":",color_match[key]  )
```

Output:

```
Enter the name of your friend: bob
Enter your friend's favorite color: blue
Enter the name of your friend: rob
Enter your friend's favorite color: BLuE
Enter the name of your friend: tom
Enter your friend's favorite color: green
Enter the name of your friend: 
Enter your friend's favorite color: 
{'blue': 'bob, rob', 'green': 'tom'}
blue: bob, rob
green: tom
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I didn't know you could use =+ like that!  I also was not familiar with the .keys

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would make more sense to structure your dictionary the other way around, with the Keys being each color, and the values consisting of lists of friends that chose that color.

This can be done like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

color_match = defaultdict(list)
while True:
    value = input('Enter the name of your friend: ')
    if value == '0':
        break
    key = input('Enter your friend\'s favorite color: ')
    if not (key and value):
        break
    color_match[key].append(value)

print(color_match)

for key in color_match:
        print(f"{key}: {color_match[key]}")
```

Using your example, the above would print out:

```
Blue: ['Eric', 'Bob']
Red: ['Tom']
```

Using defaultdict with a default value of the "list" type instead of a regular dictionary allows us to append list values even if the specified key does not yet exist.

If you wanted the printed results to simply be each name separated by commas, you could achieve that with a small modification to the last few lines:

```
for key in color_match:
    array_string = ", ".join(color_match[key])
    print(f"{key}: {array_string}")
```

One thing to keep in mind is that "Red" and "red" will result in two different dictionary keys, as they are not identical strings.  To protect against this, it might be useful to add the line:

```
value = value[0].upper() + value[1:].lower()
```

after the `"if value == '0':` block.

This will ensure that "blue", "bLue", "BLUE", or any other variation will be captured as "Blue".